# Can gcc compile C++17 code with older third party libraries?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

C++17 has removed several language and library features that were deprecated in C++11.

As a result, some older library headers that utilize [exception specifications](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) or `register` variables outright don't compile.

Does gcc have a flag to allow C++17 code to include features that were removed?

Comment: Other than `-std=c++11`, you mean?

Comment: You were supposed to fix those. You've had *six years* to do so. And it's not like `register` or exception specifications were actually doing anything...

Comment: `auto_ptr` compiles with `-std=c++1z` on Wandbox: https://wandbox.org/permlink/w5o84WttALb35e4u. What do you mean by "my older library headers don't compile"?

Comment: @ks1322 one example is Oracle's ["SQL Connector"](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/1.1.html) which is still using exception specifications.  (sad face)

Comment: If you are not going to use anything introduced in C++17 you can use `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`.

Comment: `#define register` `#define throw(...)` Technically UB, but might work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often, you can get back features removed from the language with `-fpermissive`.  This is does not work for `throw` specifiers in GCC7, which is arguably a bug, and you should report it as such.  After all, `-fpermissive` enables such goodies as implicit `int`s.

The `register` removal results just in a warning for now, easily disabled with `-Wno-register`.

Answer (score 0):

auto_ptr and register should be warnings. You could get them away with -Wno-register -Wno-deprecated-declarations. I don't know if you could do something about the throw error.

Comment: "*auto_ptr and register should be warnings.*" Not if it conforms to the C++17 specification. Warnings are for deprecated things. They weren't deprecated; they were *removed* (because they'd been deprecated some time before).

Comment: @NicolBolas g++ 7.1.1 with -std=c++17 does it on my machine and the question was about gcc.

Comment: @NicolBolas, does standard prohibit compiler vendors to provide removed features in c++17 mode as extensions? It removed description and reserved some names, but this doesn't seem to be enough for that.

Comment: @xaizek: The standard is silent about any compiler extensions. An implementation can do whatever it wants with ill-formed programs, so long as a diagnostic is produced. But considering that the features were removed after a period of deprecation, the expectation is clear that compilation in accord with the standard is expected to halt.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yet the whole point of the "zombie names" clause is to allow implementations to continue providing the removed features while remaining conforming.

Comment: @T.C.: I am highly amused that the section you're talking about is literally named "Zombie names". [zombie.names] is a real part of the Standard for Programming Language C++. That's wonderful! ;)